# non-parametric inference assumption

Tags: nonparametric, sample, population

This may be somewhat of a philosophical or foundational question.  In parametric inference, we make a distribution assumption to relate sample to population.  Even in a non-parametric technique such as bootstrapping, there would seem to be an assumption, if not about distribution, relating population and sample, e.g., that the relationship between resample statistics and the original data statistic is the same or similar to the relationship between the original data statistic and population.  I have not come across any discussion of something similar for non-parametric inference techniques based on rank/order statistics or binomial distribution.  Is it something along the lines of ordering/ranking relationships in the sample being the same as in the population?  Is there any good discussion of this that I can be directed to?

Answer (score 0):

The rank-based statistics you're thinking of are all *permutation tests* (... after some form of rank-transformation of the data).

Permutation tests don't have to be used with a rank transformation. However, one big advantage of using ranks (aside more obvious ones like relative robustness to large outliers) is that you can produce *tables* for them. This is not possible for permutation tests on raw data (the null distribution of the test statistic had to be computed anew for each sample), making it ideal for pre-computer days or teaching to people who may have difficulty doing some things with computers.

That said, permutation tests on the data allow you to use 'natural' statistics for your problem (like a Pearson correlation, say, because you're interested in linear correlation), rather than having to use a rank based quantity that may not quite measure what you want.

Permutation tests on the original data and bootstrap tests are similar/related. Most obviously, they both involve resampling the data (they're both 'resampling tests').

The obvious difference in simple cases is that bootstrapping involves sampling with replacement (so your next 're'-sample may see one observation come up two or three times and another observation not come up at all) while permutation tests involve sampling without replacement so the entirety of the original sample (or more generally of whatever quantity is being exchanged) appears in any given 're'-sample.

There's also the fact that there are $n^n$ potential bootstrap re-samples but typically a much smaller number of permutation re-samples (e.g. for a two-sample test like a permuted t-test or a Wilcoxon rank-sum test, there are $n \choose n_1$ distinct permuted samples); this makes complete enumeration (i.e. exact calculation avoiding the random sampling error due to resampling) feasible at substantially larger sample sizes than you could with the bootstrap.

Permutation tests don't rely on the convergence of $\hat{F}_n$ to $F$; their basis for inference is the exchangeability of the quantities being 'permuted'.

So, for example, in an experiment you can use randomization to treatment as a basis to argue for exchangeability (and hence to potentially establish a difference that was not due to random variation, or indeed to effects that should have been randomized out by the allocation-to-treatment scheme), even if you didn't have a true random sample from some population of interest. However, if you want to argue back from sample to a population (to claim that this treatment will work across the whole population), however, a biased sample would interfere with that step (if you had nobody under 18 in your sample you would lack a statistical basis for extending that argument to young people, for example).

Because they don't rely on that convergence to $F$, permutation tests aren't 'large sample'; they work as intended down to small sample sizes (in the sense that they're 'exact' tests, though at very small sample sizes there may not be many available significance levels).

On the downside, suitable exchangeable quantities may not exist in complicated models. Sometimes approximately exchangeable quantities are substituted (e.g. permuting residuals in multiple regression); in that case such a permutation test becomes conceptually even more like a bootstrap.

I'm less clear on exactly what things you're including with the mention of the binomial. If you're referring to say a sign test, that's also a permutation test.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I think that what I was missing was the concept of exchangeability, and I will have to delve into that some more (I am looking at a paper by Lindley and Novick), and the implication of it for going from sample to population.  Do I understand correctly that the separate assumption of at least conceptual exchangeability (whether approximate or exact) is necessary to justify non-parametric results such as confidence intervals?  Otherwise, permutations on a sample would still be a result only for the sample, and would say nothing about the population?